# Varying the order of method calling for different instances of a class

Tags: java, methods, call

What is the best way of manipulating the order things are done based on some conditions (other than writing them again with the different order)?

Let's say there is a Person class and each object of Person represents a different human.

```
class Person{
    int eatingPriority = 3;
    int sleepingPriority = 2;
    int recreationPriority = 1;

    void eat() {/*eats*/}
    void sleep() {/*sleeps*/}
    void watchTv() {/*watches tv*/}

    void satisfyNeeds() {
        //HOW TO DO THIS
    }
}
```

How can I make the `satisfyNeeds()` methods call the other three methods based on their priority?

Note: I want to make it clear that priorities can change from Person to Person.

Comment: The easiest is to create an abstract class with 2 methods : `getPriority()` and `run()`. Then create an insance for each activity. Finally, you can put instances of those activities in a list and sort them by priority.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle or use a `PriorityQueue`

Comment: I've been asked the purpose of the program. We are trying to find the cleanest way of manipulating the flow of the program. In this example let's assume that we are creating an AI for a game that has simulated people in it.  If you are both hungry and tired would you sleep or eat first? If your sleeping priority is higher you sleep first, otherwise you eat before sleeping. Also it is possible to change the priorities on the fly. We can measure the sleep and food needs and set a priority based on this. Note that the code in the question is a simplified version to demonstrate the problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this code

```
import java.util.Arrays;  // must be imported
int[] priorities = {sleepPriority, eatPriority, recreationPriority};
Arrays.sort(priorities);
for (int i=priorities.length-1; 0<=i; i--) {
    int priority = priorities[i];
    if (priority == sleepingPriority) { sleep(); }
    if (priority == eatingPriority) { eat(); }
    if (priority == recreationPriority) { watchTv(); }
}
```

Basically, it puts the priorities in an array, sorts the array and runs a for loop on it to run the functions.

Comment: requires -1 to the starting i value. Causes outOfBoundsException. 
`int i=priorities.length -1`

Comment: Oh.. I will check it now.

Comment: OK I fixed it. It should work now. I added the-1 as @WVrock pointed out.

Comment: I've tested this and it works. I think this is the simplest solution. No extra classes or interfaces. It even uses only a single import.

Comment: @WVrock: my solution doesn’t even need a single import ;^)

Comment: @Holger I'm planning to add more than 10 elements. So your solution wouldn't work for me. This answer even inspired me to write a getMaxOfABunchOfInts method without calling max inside of a max inside of a max.

Comment: @ColdConfusion with `switch` statements it will be more expressive.

Comment: @AntonDozortsev `switch case` wouldn't work with the dynamic variables.

Answer (score 13):

You can do this with 1 class and 1 interface.

```
public class Person {
    int eatingPriority = 3;
    int sleepingPriority = 2;
    int recreationPriority = 1;

    PriorityQueue<Action> actions;

    void eat() { }

    void sleep() { }

    void watchTv() { }

    public Person() {
        actions = new PriorityQueue<Action>(new Comparator<Action>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Action o1, Action o2) {
                return o2.getPriority() - o1.getPriority();
            }
        });

        actions.add(new Action() {
            @Override
            public int getPriority() {
                return eatingPriority;
            }
            @Override
            public void execute() {
                eat();
            }
        });

        actions.add(new Action() {
            @Override
            public int getPriority() {
                return sleepingPriority;
            }
            @Override
            public void execute() {
                sleep();
            }
        });

        actions.add(new Action() {
            @Override
            public int getPriority() {
                return recreationPriority;
            }
            @Override
            public void execute() {
                watchTv();
            }
        });
    }

    public void satisfyNeeds() {
        for (Action action : actions) {
            action.execute();
        }
    }

    interface Action {
        public int getPriority();
        public void execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also keep your class structure and call your methods eat(), sleep() and watchTv() from appropriate execute() methods.

Comment: Thanks! Nice idea, it's reasonable to use PriorityQueue here instead of ArrayList.

Comment: Yes, sorry I removed my comment above to write a more explaining one. The advantage of PriorityQueue over ArrayList in this case would be that the sorting process is made at each adding of element, and especially "persisted". By using ArrayList, anytime you call the `satisfyNeeds`, you have to sort the list, could be really consuming in some use cases.

Comment: Yes, great like that ;)

Comment: I even would subclass the Action class to have some meaningful terms like `SleepAction`, and keep Open/closed Principle ;)

Comment: I was thinking about that :) But it depends. If we had 100 different Actions, we would make more classes and it might have made the whole structure complicated.

Comment: Adding more classes when it makes sense (and that is the case here) is really better than putting various and changing responsibilities to the same class. I enjoy thinking about unit testing. When your class doesn't change, you don't have to worry about break unit tests/ functionalities about all the use cases. Indeed, you just ADD code, leaving the main code intact. Even don't have to replay them. Moreover, your class Person would be reusable => the whole point of OOP.  The rule is: "extract all what is dynamic in your class". What is dynamic here is the nature and number of person's actions.

Comment: @Mik378 Java 8 would remove a lot of it.

Answer (score 11):

Here is another possible implementation :

```
abstract class Need {
  abstract void satisfy();
}

class Eat extends Need {
  @Override
  public void satisfy() { /* eat ...*/}
}

class Sleep extends Need {
  @Override
  public void satisfy() { /* sleep ...*/}
}

class DrinkBeer extends Need {
  @Override
  public void satisfy() { /* drink beer ...*/}
}

class Person{
  // TreeMap will sort the map in the key's natural order (a int here)
  private Map<Integer, Need> needs = new TreeMap<>();    

 Person() {
   add(new Eat(), 3);
   add(new Sleep(), 2);
   add(new DrinkBeer(), 1);
 }

 void add(Need need, int priority) {
   needs.put(Integer.valueOf(priority), need);
 }

 void satisfyNeeds() {
    for(Need need : needs.values())
      need.satisfy();
  }
}
```

Comment: `needs.put(Integer.valueOf(priority), need)` can be written as simply `needs.put(priority, need)`.

Answer (score 10):

This solution would require Java 8:

```
class Person {

    void eat() {};
    void sleep() {};
    void watchTv() {};

    // Being in a List you can easily reorder the needs when you want to
    List<Runnable> needs = Arrays.asList(this::eat, this::sleep);

    // Alternatively, you can use a Map<Runnable, Integer> where the value is your
    // priority and sort it (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/109383/1296402)

    void satisfyNeeds() {
        needs.forEach(Runnable::run);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? Am I supposed to write  `needs = Arrays.asList(() -> eat(), () -> sleep());` with the desired order whenever I want to reorder it?

Comment: @WVrock You can initially define the order and later reorder it whenever it changes. Or use a `Map` if you have static priority values as integers (see the link). Maybe you have "presets", like `final List<Runnable> needsDuringDayTime = ....; final List<Runnable> needsDuringNightTime = ...` and then you set them in `satisfyNeeds()`: `List<Runnable> needs = isDayTime() ? needsDuringDayTime : needsDuringNightTime`.

Comment: @WVrock Or imagine you have counters or timestamps for last meals, sleep times or TV sessions and so the needs change dynamically. You'd sort the `List` with a custom `Comparator` like `Collections.sort(needs, customComparator);`

Comment: Is `() -> eat()` different from `new Runnable() { public void run() { eat() } }` or just nicer to type?

Comment: @Random832 It's the same. I updated my answer to make it yet a little better to read.

Answer (score 5):

Finding the right order of three elements can be done simply like this:

```
 void satisfyNeeds() {
     boolean eatFirst = eatingPriority>Math.max(sleepingPriority,recreationPriority);
     if(eatFirst) eat();
     if(sleepingPriority>recreationPriority) {
         sleep();
         watchTv();
     }
     else {
         watchTv();
         sleep();
     }
     if(!eatFirst) eat();
  }
```

Of course, it won’t scale if you raise the number of actions. For a higher number you might look at one of the other answers.

Answer (score 4):

You should introduce a map property into `Person` class, where prioritize methods, for example:

```
class Person {

...
private Map<Integer, Method> methodsPriority = new HashMap<>();
...
 public Person setEatingPriority(int priority) {

  methodsPriority.put(priority, /* put 'eat' method reference here*/);
  return this;
 }

 public Person setSleepingPriority(int priority) {

  methodsPriority.put(priority, /* put 'sleep' method reference here*/);
  return this;
 }

 public Person setWatchingTVPriority(int priority) {

  methodsPriority.put(priority, /* put 'watch TV' method reference here*/);
  return this;
 }

 public void satisfyNeeds() {

  Collection<Integer> keys = methodsPriority.keySet();
  Collections.sort(keys);
  for(Integer key: keys)
   methodsPriority.get(key).invoke(this);
 }



...
}
```

And it can be used in next manner:

```
Person Anna = new Person()
.setEatingPriority(1)
.setSleepingPriority(2)
.setWatchingTVPriority(3);

Person Bob = new Person()
.setEatingPriority(3)
.setSleepingPriority(2)
.setWatchingTVPriority(1);

Anna.satisfyNeeds();
Bob.satisfyNeeds();
```